# I have 2 columns with values. Trying to find which values in Column A that are not in Column B

Tags: excel, list, multiple-columns, rows, distinct-values

Column A has 868 Rows and Column B has 452 rows. How do I **find all the values in Column A that are not in Column B?**

Answer (score 0):

A quick way would be to use a helper column, let's say C.  You can use `Countif()` to quickly check, then `If()` to make it logical:

`=If(Countif($B:$B,$A1)=0,"Not in Col. B","")`

I wouldn't use the entire `B` column, for calculating/processing time, so adjust that range as necessary.  You could then sort by column C to bring all "Not in Col. B" to the top.

Edit: Ah, it's basically @pnut's suggestion, with a little more for ease of reading.  Also, probably would want to add `If($A1<>"",...)` just to make sure blank cells don't return "Not in Col. B"

Answer (score 0):

If the values are distinct, then easier alternative with conditional formatting:

Select both ranges or columns > Home > Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cell Rules > Duplicate Values... > Unique > OK